# ResultSet in Zend Framework 2 does not work with toArray()

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2

I thought that I would be able to use `toArray()` on my Zend resultset, but I find that using `toArray()` fails with the message:

> Rows as part of this DataSource, with type object cannot be cast to an array

What I thought would work was something like

`return new JsonModel($collections->toArray());`

But that fails with the above error message.

Here is the Collection, a small class

```php
class Collection
{
public $collectionID;
public $name;

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->collectionID = (!empty($data['collectionID'])) ? $data['collectionID'] : null;
    $this->name = (!empty($data['name'])) ? $data['name'] : null;
}

// Add the following method:
public function getArrayCopy()
{
    return get_object_vars($this);
}


}
```

If I add my own

```
public function toArray()
{
  return array(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

I can coerce it into doing what I'd expect, but I'm not sure this is the best approach. Also if I use that in conjunction with `JsonModel` the JSON outputted  will also contain variables from settings.global.php

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the records, as it won't fetch all in one go. So something like:

```
$m = array();

foreach($resultSet as $r)
    $m[] = (array)$r;
```

Or else try:

```
$resultSet = (array)resultSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use, `$result->getArrayCopy()`
if it doesn't work you could try adding to Collection this function

```
 public function getArrayCopy()
 {
     return get_object_vars($this);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that generates the same error message for me.